# Why derivative of $(3x^2 - 2)^{\frac{2}{x}}$ can be written as $(3x^2 - 2)^{\frac{2}{x}} \cdot (ln(3x^2 - 2)\cdot\frac{2}{x})'$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am struggling with derivatives of exponents functions...

Why derivative of $(3x^2 - 2)^{\frac{2}{x}}$ can be written as $(3x^2 - 2)^{\frac{2}{x}} \cdot (ln(3x^2 - 2)\cdot\frac{2}{x})'$?

Where does that property come from?

Please provide a complete explanation with the rules you are using, otherwise for me its difficult, since I am quite newbie

Comment: $(3x^2 - 2)^{\frac{2}{x}}$ can be written $$\\exp{\left(\left(\frac{2}{x}\right) \ln(3x^2 - 2)\right)}$$

Comment: Exactly, perfectly and monumentally correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Using:$ f=e^{\log f}$, We have:

$$
f(x)^{g(x)}=e^{g(x)\log f(x)}
$$

Than use chaining rule for derivative.

We have:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} e^{[ g(x)\log f(x) ]}=e^{[ g(x)\log f(x) ]}\dfrac{d}{dx}[ g(x)\log f(x) ]
$$

Comment: I've added to my answer.